# Parsing XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I need to read a XML and use it after this on a table to populate a chart. This is my **XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Export>
  <Columns>
    <Dim1>Heures</Dim1>
    <Metric1>Visites</Metric1>
  </Columns>
  <Row Dim1="0h" Metric1="5347" Var1="" Diff1="5347" Rat1="0,0728940874947173" Metric12="0,0728940874947173" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="116946" Var2="" Diff2="116946" Rat2="0,35501654473149" Metric5="21,8713297175987" Var5="" Diff5="21,8713297175987" />
  <Row Dim1="1h" Metric1="3121" Var1="" Diff1="3121" Rat1="0,0425476803948032" Metric12="0,0425476803948032" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="7831" Var2="" Diff2="7831" Rat2="0,023772805925746" Metric5="2,50913168856136" Var5="" Diff5="2,50913168856136" />
  <Row Dim1="2h" Metric1="2362" Var1="" Diff1="2362" Rat1="0,0322004553324336" Metric12="0,0322004553324336" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="6513" Var2="" Diff2="6513" Rat2="0,0197717130627485" Metric5="2,75740897544454" Var5="" Diff5="2,75740897544454" />
  <Row Dim1="3h" Metric1="1591" Var1="" Diff1="1591" Rat1="0,0216896377789593" Metric12="0,0216896377789593" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="5406" Var2="" Diff2="5406" Rat2="0,0164111593454965" Metric5="3,39786297925833" Var5="" Diff5="3,39786297925833" />
  <Row Dim1="4h" Metric1="1692" Var1="" Diff1="1692" Rat1="0,0230665412457568" Metric12="0,0230665412457568" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="5630" Var2="" Diff2="5630" Rat2="0,0170911629883732" Metric5="3,3274231678487" Var5="" Diff5="3,3274231678487" />
  <Row Dim1="5h" Metric1="2206" Var1="" Diff1="2206" Rat1="0,030073752948073" Metric12="0,030073752948073" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="10108" Var2="" Diff2="10108" Rat2="0,0306851643848092" Metric5="4,58204895738894" Var5="" Diff5="4,58204895738894" />
  <Row Dim1="6h" Metric1="4684" Var1="" Diff1="4684" Rat1="0,063855602361185" Metric12="0,063855602361185" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="16577" Var2="" Diff2="16577" Rat2="0,0503233053034213" Metric5="3,53906917164816" Var5="" Diff5="3,53906917164816" />
  <Row Dim1="7h" Metric1="10821" Var1="" Diff1="10821" Rat1="0,147519528853626" Metric12="0,147519528853626" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="34800" Var2="" Diff2="34800" Rat2="0,105643423089767" Metric5="3,21596894926532" Var5="" Diff5="3,21596894926532" />
  <Row Dim1="8h" Metric1="19478" Var1="" Diff1="19478" Rat1="0,265537878478045" Metric12="0,265537878478045" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="66604" Var2="" Diff2="66604" Rat2="0,202191797456058" Metric5="3,41944758188726" Var5="" Diff5="3,41944758188726" />
  <Row Dim1="9h" Metric1="22051" Var1="" Diff1="22051" Rat1="0,300614835112402" Metric12="0,300614835112402" Var12="" Diff12="-2147483648" Metric2="58995" Var2="" Diff2="58995" Rat2="0,179092923712091" Metric5="2,675388871253" Var5="" Diff5="2,675388871253" />
</Export>
```

Then this is what I have tried, but nothing happens, I've only a blank page, can someone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get( "graph.xml", function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
        var heures,
            nbr,
            divItems = $( "<div/>", {
                "class" : "items"
            });

        $( data ).find( "Export" ).children().each( function( i, item){
            $( item ).children().each( function( j , jtem ){
                heures = $( jtem ).attr( "Dim1" );
                nbr = $( jtem ).attr( "Metric1" );

                $( divItems )
                    .clone()
                    .html( '<a href="' + heures + '">' + nbr + '</a>')
                    .appendTo( "#xml" );
            });
        });
         </script>

         </head>
         <body>
          <div id="xml"></div>
          </body>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each `Row` instead:

```
var $divItems = $( "<div/>", {
    "class" : "items"
});

$(data).find("Row").each(function(i, item) {
    var heures = $(item).attr("Dim1");
    var nbr = $(item).attr("Metric1");
    $divItems.clone()
        .html('<a href="' + heures + '">' + nbr + '</a>')
        .appendTo("#xml");
});
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vjsqw/)**.